# Implementing custom taxes on pancake swap

Tags: solidity, blockchain, bsc, pancakeswap

I wanted to implement a custom tax for pancake swap.
currently, iam using pancake swap testnet ones.

iam stucking at these points.
how to add custom tax for on swapping or at time of creating liquidity.
In my contracts, if i added validation on transfer and transferFunction to take tax

Or any other ways to understand & implement  a way for my logic to work

Answer (score 0):

You would have to deduct the user's amount before calling in the swap function

1. Take the users amount in your swap function, deduct the tax %
2. Call in pancakeswaps `SwapExactToken` function in the custom swap function